# Create bytes from IEEE 754 single-precision (32-bit) floating point (string represented)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a floating point to byte array/stream using javascript. 
My javascript code is passed with a string represented floating point values defined like this:

**Code from AS library:**

```
        while (buffer.bytesAvailable > 0) 
        {
            ret += buffer.readFloat().toString() + ";";
        }
```

The code above is a Actionscript code, in which the function is defined:

```
readFloat():Number
Reads an IEEE 754 single-precision (32-bit) floating-point number from the byte stream.
```

Since I can't modify the AS library as it is already compiled to SWF and exported functions for javascript, I only can resort to converting the output back to bytes with Javascript.

What are the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse binary float with that class : http://jsfromhell.com/classes/binary-parser